# define object type with dynamic number of key and value and also that values can have string or number value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-tsx

i have a project with nextjs and typescript.i have a function with name of submit func.
this function accept three argument.type with string type base end point with string type and my problem is whit third argument and i can't handle type for this argument.i want this argument accepted a object with dynamic number of keys and values and also that values can have string or number value.
this is my submit func

```js
 interface values {
    [key: string]: object;
}
 const submitFunc = (type: string, baseEndPoint: string, values: values) => {
 //some code
 }
```

for more explanation i want for example call my function as follow

```js
submitFunc('login', '/auth/mobile', {
            'mobile': 0912855838,
            'password': 'serer434312'
        });
```

or

```js
submitFunc('name', '/auth/name', {
            'name':'Max'
        });
```

and Etc

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface values {
    [key: string]: string | number;
}
```

This will define an object with key as string and values as either string or number type

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Record<string, string | number>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype):

```
const submitFunc = (
  type: string,
  baseEndPoint: string,
  values: Record<string, string | number>
) => {
  // your code here
};
```

Also, in your particular case, you may also [join multiple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types):

```
type Values = { mobile: number; password: string } | { name: string };

const submitFunc = (type: string, baseEndPoint: string, values: Values) => {
  // your code here
};
```

Or if you want to have all the combinations of those three keys, you can define [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties):

```
type Values = { mobile?: number; password?: string; name?: string };

const submitFunc = (type: string, baseEndPoint: string, values: Values) => {
  // your code here
};
```